# JavaScript onclick only works once and doesn't update

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have the following php code:

```
foreach ($facility_names as $name)
{
    echo '<div class="row facility-name">';
    echo '<button id="facilityNameLeft" class="btn btn-default btn-fill btn-menu" onclick="javascript:showDetails()">'.$name.'</button>';
    echo '</div>';
}

<h1 id="facilityNameRight">Aquatics Centre</h1>
```

That should simply show a button inside a div for every $name (right?).

And this piece of javascript:

```
function showDetails() {
    var facilityName = document.getElementById("facilityNameLeft").innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("facilityNameRight").innerHTML = facilityName;
}
```

Now, I am new to javascript, but I can't figure out why the onclick only works once before I have to reload the page and why it only updates the innerHTML of the h1 tag with the value of the first $name (no matter which of the buttons I press).

Comment: "id" values have to be unique on the page. You're re-using the same id for each group of elements.

Comment: This worked! Thank you!